# Is there a Python equivalent to the spearman2 function from the Hmisc package for R?

Tags: python, r

The [documentation](http://ftp.auckland.ac.nz/software/CRAN/doc/packages/Hmisc.pdf) (page 149) of the Hmisc package of R says:

spearman2 computes the square of Spearman’s rho rank correlation and a generalization of it in which x can relate non-monotonically to y. *This is done by computing the Spearman multiple rho-squared between (rank(x), rank(x)^2) and y.*

I am wondering if there is an equivalent function in Python? Or if someone could explain to me how to write a small function that can do the calculation emphasized in italics above, using scipy.stats.spearmanr?

Answer (score 0):

From the source code of the Hnisc package (https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/biVar.s), here is the source code of the function:

```
spearman2.default <- function(x, y, p=1, minlev=0,
                              na.rm=TRUE, exclude.imputed=na.rm, ...)
{
  if(p > 2)
    stop('p must be 1 or 2')


  y <- as.numeric(y)
  if(is.character(x))
    x <- factor(x)

  if(na.rm) {
    s <- !(is.na(x) | is.na(y))
    if(exclude.imputed) {
      im <- is.imputed(x) | is.imputed(y)
      s <- s & !im
    }
    x <- x[s]; y <- y[s]
  }
  n <- length(x)

  ## If number of non-NA values is less then 3 then return a NA
  ## value.
  if(n < 3)
    return(c(rho2=NA,F=NA,df1=0,df2=n,P=NA,n=n,'Adjusted rho2'=NA))

  ## Find the number of unique values in x
  u <- length(unique(x))

  ## If is a factor and unique values are greater then 2 then find the
  ## lm.fit.qr.bare without an intercept.
  if(is.factor(x) && u > 2) {
    if(minlev > 0) {
      x <- combine.levels(x, minlev)
      if(length(levels(x))<2) {
        warning(paste('x did not have >= 2 categories with >=',
                      minlev,'of the observations'))
        return(c(rho2=NA,F=NA,df1=0,df2=n,P=NA,n=n,'Adjusted rho2'=NA))
      }
    }

    x <- model.matrix(~x, data=data.frame(x))
    p <- ncol(x)-1
    rsquare <- lm.fit.qr.bare(x, rank(y), intercept=FALSE)$rsquared
  } else {
    x <- as.numeric(x)
    if(u < 3)
      p <- 1

    x <- rank(x)
    rsquare <-
      if(p==1)
        cor(x, rank(y))^2
      else {
        x <- cbind(x, x^2)
        lm.fit.qr.bare(x, rank(y), intercept=TRUE)$rsquared
      }
  }

  df2 <- n-p-1
  fstat <- rsquare/p/((1-rsquare)/df2)
  pvalue <- 1-pf(fstat,p,df2)
  rsqa <- 1 - (1 - rsquare)*(n-1)/df2

  x <- c(rsquare,fstat,p,df2,pvalue,n,rsqa)
  names(x) <- c("rho2","F","df1","df2","P","n","Adjusted rho2")
  x
}
```

The function `lm.fit.qr.bare` is defined in this file (https://github.com/harrelfe/Hmisc/blob/master/R/Misc.s) line 213.

Looks like you also need the `chol2inv` function, see details here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/chol2inv

It will require some work but you can definitely translate it in python. Good luck!